# Python multiprocessing for dataset preparation

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing, queue

I'm looking for shorter ways to prepare my dataset for a machine-learning task. I found that the multiprocessing library might helpful. However, because I'm a newbie in multiprocessing, I couldn't find a proper way.

I first wrote some codes like below:

```py
class DatasetReader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_list = Read_Data_from_file
        self.data = []

    def _ready_data(self, ex, idx):
        # Some complex functions that takes several minutes

    def _dataset_creator(self, queue):
        for idx, ex in enumerate(self.data_list):
            queue.put(self._ready_data(ex, idx))

    def _dataset_consumer(self, queue):
        total_mem = 0.0
        t = tqdm(range(self.num_data), total=self.num_data, desc='Building Dataset ', bar_format='{desc}:{percentage:3.0f}% ({n_fmt}/{total_fmt}) [{elapsed}<{remaining},{rate_fmt}{postfix}]')
        for idx in t:
            ins = queue.get()
            self.data.append(ins)
            gc.collect()

    def _build_dataset(self):
        queue = Queue()
        creator = Process(target=self._dataset_creator, args=(queue,))
        consumer = Process(target=self._dataset_consumer, args=(queue,))
        creator.start()
        consumer.start()

        queue.close()
        queue.join_thread()

        creator.join()
        consumer.join()
```

However, in my opinion, because the `_dataset_creator` processes data (here `_ready_data`) in **serial manner**, this would not be helpful for reducing time consumption.

So, I modified the code to generate multiple processes that process one datum:

```py
class DatasetReader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_list = Read_Data_from_file
        self.data = []

    def _ready_data(self, ex, idx):
        # Some complex functions that takes several minutes

    def _dataset_creator(self, ex, idx, queue):
        queue.put(self._ready_data(ex, idx))

    def _dataset_consumer(self, queue):
        total_mem = 0.0
        t = tqdm(range(self.num_data), total=self.num_data, desc='Building Dataset ', bar_format='{desc}:{percentage:3.0f}% ({n_fmt}/{total_fmt}) [{elapsed}<{remaining},{rate_fmt}{postfix}]')
        for idx in t:
            ins = queue.get()
            self.data.append(ins)
            gc.collect()

    def _build_dataset(self):
        queue = Queue()
        for idx, ex in enumerate(self.data_list):
            p = Process(target=self._dataset_creator, args=(ex, idx, queue,))
            p.start()
        consumer = Process(target=self._dataset_consumer, args=(queue,))
        consumer.start()

        queue.close()
        queue.join_thread()

        consumer.join()
```

However, this returns me errors:

```
Process Process-18:  
Traceback ~~~  
RuntimeError: can't start new thread  
Traceback ~~~  
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Could you help me to process complex data in a parallel way?

EDIT 1:

Thanks to @tdelaney, I can reduce the time consumption by generating `self.num_worker` processes (16 in my experiment):

```py
    def _dataset_creator(self, pid, queue):
        for idx, ex in list(enumerate(self.data_list))[pid::self.num_worker]:
            queue.put(self._ready_data(ex, idx))

    def _dataset_consumer(self, queue):
        t = tqdm(range(self.num_data), total=self.num_data, desc='Building Dataset ', bar_format='{desc}:{percentage:3.0f}% ({n_fmt}/{total_fmt}) [{elapsed}<{remaining},{rate_fmt}{postfix}]')
        for _ in t:
            ins = queue.get()
            self.data[ins['idx']] = ins

    def _build_dataset(self):
        queue = Queue()
        procs = []
        for pid in range(self.num_worker):
            p = Process(target=self._dataset_creator, args=(pid, queue,))
            procs.append(p)
            p.start()
        consumer = Process(target=self._dataset_consumer, args=(queue,))
        consumer.start()

        queue.close()
        queue.join_thread()

        for p in procs:
            p.join()
        consumer.join()
```

Comment: Random thoughts - You fail at process #18 - running fewer at a time may help. Is `Read_Data_from_file` a bunch of data you've read from a file - and can you do the reading part in the process? Is the result of `_ready_data` large? And are its calculations something done in python or in some subsystem like `pandas` or `scipy` that do work in C after releasing the GIL? `gc.collect` likely doesn't do much unless you've got a lot of circular referenced data. But if `t` and `inx` are large, its a good idea to delete them as soon as you are done with them.

Comment: @tdelaney I think I can generate a limited number of processes, split data with the number and process part of the data one each process. Maybe I should try so. Because the whole data is in one file, I think it'll be hard to split the data reading part, unless I split the data file. The result of `_ready_data` is quite large (about 200~300 KB). I think all the calculations are done in python. I think I don't need `gc.collect` any more. Thanks for your comments! :)

Comment: Its an interesting problem. Is this mac/linux where processes are forked, or windows where processes are spawned? If forked, you don't have to put` ex` on the queue, its already in the child process space.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm using Centos currently, which would be the Linux system, but I couldn't understand the difference between fork and spawn. :( Could you share some references or something that might be helpful? Thanks for your help!

Comment: On fork, subprocess has a copy-on-write view of the parent memory at the point the process was created. So don't pass `self.data_list[idex]` to the child, its already there. On spawn, python has to pickle the parent state and unpickle it in the child. So, you have to pass `self.data_list[idx]`. But be careful, when you created that subprocess, and want to use `self`, you may find that it copied __all__ of the `data_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to sketch out what a solution with a multiprocessing pool would look like. I got rid of the consumer process completely because it looks like the parent process is just waiting anyway (and needs the data eventually) so it can be the consumer. So, I set up a pool and use `imap_unordered` to handle passing the data to the worker.

I guessed that the data processing doesn't really need the DatasetReader at all and moved it out to its own function. On Windows, either the entire `DataReader` object is serialized to the subprocess (including data you don't want) or the child version of the object is incomplete and may crash when you try to use it.

Either way, changes made to a `DatasetReader` object in the child processes aren't seen in the parent. This can be unexpected if the parent is dependent on updated state in that object. Its best to severely bracket what's happening in subprocesses, in my opinion.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, get_start_method, cpu_count

# moved out of class (assuming it is not class dependent) so that
# the entire DatasetReader object isn't pickled and sent to
# the child on spawning systems like Microsoft Windows

def _ready_data(idx_ex):
    idx, ex = idx_ex
    # Some complex functions that take several minutes
    result = complex_functions(ex)
    return (idx, result)


class DatasetReader:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data_list = Read_Data_from_file
        self.data = [None] * len(data_list)

    def _ready_data_fork(self, idx):
        # on forking system, call worker with object data
        return _ready_data((idx, self.data_list[idx]))

    def run(self):

        t = tqdm(range(self.num_data), total=self.num_data, desc='Building Dataset ',
            bar_format='{desc}:{percentage:3.0f}% ({n_fmt}/{total_fmt}) '
                '[{elapsed}<{remaining},{rate_fmt}{postfix}]')

        pool = Pool(min(cpu_count, len(self.data_list)))
        if get_start_method() == 'fork':
            # on forking system, self.data_list is in child process and
            # we only pass the index
            result_iter = pool.imap_unordered(self._ready_data_fork, 
                    (idx for idx in range(len(data_list))),
                    chunksize=1)
        else:
            # on spawning system, we need to pass the data
            result_iter = pool.imap_unordered(_ready_data,
                    enumerate(self.data_list,
                    chunksize=1)

        for idx, result in result_iter:
            next(t)
            self.data[idx] = result

        pool.join()
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand that you've tried to explain! On the other hand, it might be hard to apply `fork`ing features currently, because the `_ready_data` uses lots of `self` functions and variables. :( Maybe I should check if I can move it out of the class so that I can avoid pickling entire DatasetReader object. Anyway, thanks for your help with kind explanation!

Comment: Its not necessarily bad to use self on a forking system, just know that you are working with a snapshot of the object at the moment of the fork. One problem is long term maintenance - its easy to update code in a way that doesn't work in the subprocesses. You may be able to partition your class by extracting the data calculation methods into a different class. They may only have been in this class for convenience in the first place. Separation of concerns by creating more focused classes can be a good thing. I don't know your environment, just saying it in general.